# Vibrations in one of the pedals

Tags: repair, pedals, bearings, vibration

I feel vibrations in one of the pedals when I put my weight on it.

It feels like the ball bearing is broken or something. Is that possible?

How difficult is it to fix the ball bearings on the pedals if you think that's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of pedal? A photo would be very helpful, otherwise all anyone can say is "yes, some pedals can be fixed".

Comment: The pedals are the most common place to experience a bearing failure, presumably because they are not as well sealed and are exposed more to dirt and dust.  Sometimes you can repack the bearings and recover, but for some pedal styles this is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can squirt some liquid lube in the pedal axle and it eventually wicks its way to the bearings on the inside.  However this won't do much for bearings on the outside end of the axle.

Some pedals can be disassembled for servicing and ball replacement, depends totally on what your pedals look like.

We can tell you more if you post a clear sharp photo of the pedal.

The easiest solution is to buy a new pair of pedals and swap them over.  You'll need either a hex driver or a special thin spanner of the right size, and to know the left side pedal is threaded backwards.   Or a bike shop would throw the new pedals on for nothing or very little cost.

You may also find that squirting some sort of lubricant into the pedal may also work loose any grit or muck that has gotten into the pedal - if that is the case, then simply keep squirting lubricant into the axle area of the pedal until it runs clear and then get the pedals replaced as soon as possible or repack the bearings with grease (otherwise it will keep occurring and the pedals will ultimately fail).